# Need help expanding particle system spread / divergence from 2 to 3 dimensions

Tags: c++, trigonometry, angle, particles, particle-system

I need help. I've been struggling with this for a week now and getting nowhere. I am building a 3D particle system mainly for learning and I am currently working on particle spread / divergence. In specific, introducing random direction to the particle direction so as to create something that looks more like a fountain as opposed to a solid stream.

I have been successful in getting this to work in one axis but no matter what I do, I cannot get it to work in 3 dimensions.

Here is what I am doing:

`// Compute a random angle between -180 to +180 for velocity angle x, y and z. spreadAmount is a float from 0.0 to 1.0 to control degree of spread.
    float velangrndx = spreadAmount * ((((double)(rand() % RAND_MAX) / (RAND_MAX)) - 0.5) * 360.0 * 3.14159265359 / 180.0);
    float velangrndy = spreadAmount * ((((double)(rand() % RAND_MAX) / (RAND_MAX)) - 0.5) * 360.0 * 3.14159265359 / 180.0);
    float velangrndz = spreadAmount * ((((double)(rand() % RAND_MAX) / (RAND_MAX)) - 0.5) * 360.0 * 3.14159265359 / 180.0);`



`// Compute Angles
float vsin_anglex_dir = -PF_SIN(velangrndx);
float vcos_anglex_dir = -PF_COS(velangrndx);
float vsin_angley_dir = -PF_SIN(velangrndy);
float vcos_angley_dir = -PF_COS(velangrndy);
float vsin_anglez_dir = -PF_SIN(velangrndz);
float vcos_anglez_dir = -PF_COS(velangrndz);`



        `// Assign initial velocity to velocity x, y, z. vel is a float ranging from 0.0 - 0.1 specified by user. velx, vely, and velz are also floats.
        velx = vel; vely = vel; velz = vel;`

And finally, we get to the particle spread / divergence function below. If I use only the first X axis (comment out the Y and Z) it works as it should (see images), but if I use the Y and Z axis, it works totally incorrectly. px0, py0, and pz0 are temporary float variables so as to preserve the velocity variables.

`// X Divergence
px0 = (velx * vsin_anglex_dir);
py0 = (velx * vcos_anglex_dir);
pz0 = velz;
velx = px0; vely = py0; velz = pz0;

// Y Divergence
py0 = (vely * vsin_angley_dir);
pz0 = (vely * vcos_angley_dir);
px0 = velx;
velx = px0; vely = py0; velz = pz0;

// Z Divergence
pz0 = (velz * vsin_anglez_dir);
px0 = (velz * vcos_anglez_dir);
py0 = vely;
velx = px0; vely = py0; velz = pz0;`

The velx, vely, and velz are then used to calculate for particle screen position.

This is what the particle spread looks like at 25%, 75% and 100% for the X axis only (if I comment out the Y and Z code). This works as it should and in theory, if the rest of my code was working correctly, I should get this same result for the Y and Z axis. But I don't.

[image: 25% Spread]

[image: 75% Spread]

[image: 100% Spread]

I could really use some help here. Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong and how to correctly expand the currently working spread function from 2 dimensions to 3?

Thanks,
-Richard

Comment: Any suggestions? Surely, this must be a fairly common problem? Any helpful suggestions would be highly welcome!

Comment: While this may not be directly related to your question, you are generating random points within a **cube** and converting those points to angles - that will not create a uniform distribution of angles.  You will see concentrations in areas.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your problem fully, but a fountain has a direction, one of the axis shouldn't be randomized (or at least it shouldn't be allowed to be negative)

Comment: Hi @AlessandroTeruzzi, If there is no randomization, all the particles will travel in a straight line. As you add randomization, they diverge from the path and should produce a fountain-like result. So every axis needs to receive randomization. That is what I am trying to achieve but my code only work on one axis, as you can see from the images above. I am trying to make it work for all three axis. Any thoughts?

Comment: I also do not fully understand what the problem is. A fountain has a specific direction, e.g. the z-axis. So starting with a stream along the z-axis, i.e. with velocity vectors along the z-axis, you take these vectors and randomly rotate them away from the z-axis. Are you maybe looking for spherical coordinates? I.e. take the formulas for x, y, and z on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Cartesian_coordinates), and set: r = `vel` = the magnitude of the speed; theta needs to be a random value in [0,spreadAmount*Pi]; and phi a random value in [0, 2Pi[.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely it is because the values of `velx`, `vely` and `velz` are getting overwritten on subsequent calculations. See whether the below works the way you are expecting.

```
// X Divergence
float velxXD = (velx * vsin_anglex_dir);
float velyXD = (velx * vcos_anglex_dir);
float velzXD = velz;

// Y Divergence
float velxYD = velx;
float velyYD = (vely * vsin_angley_dir);
float velzYD = (vely * vcos_angley_dir);

// Z Divergence
float velxZD = (velz * vcos_anglez_dir); 
float velyZD = vely;
float velzZD = (velz * vsin_anglez_dir);

velx=velxXD+velxYD+velxZD;
vely=velyXD+velyYD+velyZD;
velz=velzXD+velzYD+velzZD;
```

Comment: Hi William - thanks for your reply. This works to some degree. When many particles are added, it assumes the shape of a cube. I assume, this might be what Drew mentioned. I noticed this happens anytime I use addition for the velocities. Perhaps I need to rethink my entire approach? I think your answer is correct and these issues are probably related to my code so I will mark this as the correct answer but if you have any other suggestions on how to correct my approach, I would appreciate it.

Comment: My goal was simply to be able to introduce the particle divergence effect I showed in the images, per axis. But I guess it's more complicated than I thought.

Comment: Could you post the complete code snippet may be as a pastebin or a repo link as a reply to this comment?